# mail command sends body as attachment, unlike normal email client? How to stop this?

Tags: email, mail-command

I am using the `mail` command from `mailutils` on Ubuntu Linux 20.04. I am using it to send documents automatically to a service on the web which processes them. They provide an email address to which you can forward your document as an attachment.

When I use my normal email client, say, thunderbird, or SOGO mail, and manually send a document it works fine, and the document is received as expected and processed. However, when I use the mail command like this:

```
echo "The body of the email" | mail -s "just a test" someone@service.com -A my_attachment.pdf
```

the remote service acts as though it has received two documents, the actual attachment, and also the body of the email as another attachment. This makes me think the `mail` command somehow sends the body as an attachment or something in a different way to other email programs I use. The emails from `mail` look fine in my own email client.

So how do I get my emails from `mail` to look like they only have one attachment, just like my manual emails? If not possible is there an alternative command line email program on Ubuntu which will act in the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I found that `mutt` seems to work the way I want. If I do

```
echo "" | mutt -s "Email Subject" some@email.address -a attachment.pdf
```

It appears as a single attachment in the other service